# arcade physics collision callback for group vs self

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework

im checking for group collision within itself using this code

```
// creating group and adding sprites 
policeCarsGroup = game.add.group();
addPoliceCars(4 , policeCarsGroup);
```

and in the update function

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(policeCarsGroup);
```

it work fine but there is no callback function how to set it i tried

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(policeCarsGroup,function(){
        alert("");
    });
```

but it not working so the question is how to set the collision callback function .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass a second parameter to the `collide` method to check the collision against, hence it's the third parameter that is the callback.  See [the documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#collide). Try this:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(policeCarsGroup, policeCarsGroup, function() {
    alert("Collision!");
});
```

Haven't tried it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
game.physics.arcade.overlap(policeCarsGroup, policeCarsGroup,
  function() {
    alert("Collision");
  },
  null,
  this);
```

it works , i have used it several times.